# How can i get primary of a new table generated from OrderBy / GroupBy?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, visual-studio

How can I get primary of a new table generated from `OrderBy` / `GroupBy`?

```
var something = (from m in _db.Requests
                 where m.StoreID == myRequest.StoreID
                 where m.AcceptedTime != null
                 where System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.RequestTime) == today
                 group m by m.StaffID into g
                 let TotalPoints = g.Count()
                 orderby TotalPoints ascending
                 select new { User = g.Key});
```

then, I try to get the 1st result which will be the least times "m" appeared in my `Requests` table

```
var thisStaff = something.Select(o=>o.User).Take(1).ToString();
```

However, the value of "thisStaff" is not `StaffID` which is the Key of my `Request` table. The value in it is

```
SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[StaffID] AS [StaffID]
FROM ( SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [StaffID]
       FROM   ( SELECT [Extent1].[StaffID] AS [K1], COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM   [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE  ([Extent1].[StoreID] = @p__linq__0) AND
                       ([Extent1].[AcceptedTime] IS NOT NULL) AND
                       ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[RequestTime], 102) , 102)) =  @p__linq__1)
                GROUP BY [Extent1].[StaffID] ) AS [GroupBy1] ) AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Please suggest how i should change it. By the way, I've also tried using the following and get almost same result.

```
var something2 = _db.Requests
    .Where(o => o.StoreID == myRequest.StoreID)
    .Where(o => o.AcceptedTime != null)
    .Where(o => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.RequestTime) == today)
    .GroupBy(x => x.StaffID)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Count = x.Count(),
        Name = x.Key,
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
    .Take(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine, you're just lacking the method call that will call the database and return the result (a feature of EF is deferred execution), `FirstOrDefault()` should do the trick:

```
var thisStaff = something.Select(o => o.User).FirstOrDefault();
```

The value that you see is the value that the `IQueryable` you have constructed returns for its ToString method (it will be the SQL that is run against the database when the query is executed).

Comment: It appears that my query is always returning me default, which is the main problem. Guess I'll have to check my query again. Thanks for the fast reply!